# How to add optiongroup in asp:listitem

Tags: .net

How can I add optiongroup in asp:listitem.

Please give some example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a link to add optionGroup - [Dropdownlist control with <optgroup>s for asp.net (webforms)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130020/dropdownlist-control-with-optgroups-for-asp-net)

Answer (score 1):

Amazingly it is not possible with the standard control, but you can roll your own that can or use someone elses such as the one you can find here:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/DropDownListOptionGroup.aspx

Hope it helps.