# Optgroup in .NET Listbox

Tags: asp.net

I have a need to group items in the Listbox similar to the OPTGROUP in a html SELECT.

Any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dropdownlist control with <optgroup>s for asp.net (webforms)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130020/dropdownlist-control-with-optgroups-for-asp-net-webforms)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refactored Sandeep's answer:

http://jsfiddle.net/kgBr9/

HTML

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option optGroup='a'>1</option>
    <option optGroup='a'>1</option>
    <option optGroup='a'>1</option>
    <option optGroup='b'>2</option>
    <option optGroup='b'>2</option>
</select>
```

JQuery

```
function SetupOptGroups(select) {
    var optGroups=new Array();    
    var i = 0;

    $(select).find("[optGroup]").each(function(index, domEle) {
        var optGroup = $(this).attr("optGroup");
        if ($.inArray(optGroup, optGroups)==-1) optGroups[i++] = optGroup;
    });

    for(i=0; i < optGroups.length; i++){
        $("option[optGroup='"+optGroups[i]+"']").wrapAll("<optgroup label='"+optGroups[i]+"'>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Note this line should include the `$(select).find()` in order to not group ALL of your select's options into one: `$(select).find("option[optGroup='"+optGroups[i]+"']").wrapAll("<optgroup label='"+optGroups[i]+"'>");`

Comment: Is there anyway to sort the placed optGroups, I tried jQuery sort but it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

I accomplished this requirement by adding an attribute to options and attribute value will be the Optgroup name i want to have. And in the client side i used this code to render dropdown with optgroups`var optGroup = "";`

```
var i = 0;
$(this).find("option").each(function () {
    if (optGroup !== "")
        optGroup += "," + $(this).attr("OptGroup");
    else
        optGroup = $(this).attr("OptGroup");
});
var optGroups = $.unique(optGroup.split(","));
for (var optGroupEle in optGroups) {
    if ($("optgroup[label='" + optGroups[optGroupEle] + "']").html() == null)
        $("option[OptGroup='" + optGroups[optGroupEle] + "']").wrapAll("<optgroup label='" + optGroups[optGroupEle] + "'/>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an Item and disable, change the color, the final efect is the same, i.e.

> itemVersion.Attributes.Add("disabled", "true")
>   itemVersion.Attributes.Add("style", "color:#CCCCCC")
>   ddlAspectoOrigen.Items.Add(itemVersion)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [HTML SELECT control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlselect%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and access all properties of this from the codebehind like a listbox. You only need to add the label `runat="server"`.

Comment: While this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include more of the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.