# Adding line to ASP.NET to ListBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I need a line added to a listbox in ASP.NET to provide some separation from the many options the user can choose from.  Currently, we have over 20 different options for the user to choose and I need to put the most popular up top.  I have the logic that puts the popular option on top, but think a line in the listbox will help the user separate them from the rest of the list.  The listbox items are populated in the code behind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the optgroup tag to give separation.

```
<select>
   <option value="XX"/>
   <optgroup label="separation"/>
   <option value="BB"/>
</select>
```

To give only a line you will need to do some trickery. See below

```
<style type="text/css">
    optgroup {border-bottom:solid thin black; width:100%;}
</style>
<select>
   <option value="XX"/>
   <optgroup label=" "/>
   <option value="BB"/>
</select>
```

If your data is already loaded you could run some jquery after.

```
$('select option[value="XX"]').after('<optgroup label=""/>');
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no out-of-the box possibility to create option-groups from DropDownLists nor Listboxes in asp.net.

Found those articles providing a server-side and client-side solution to achieve what you are looking for:

[Optgroup in .NET Listbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242664/optgroup-in-net-listbox)

[Dropdownlist control with <optgroup>s for asp.net (webforms)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130020/dropdownlist-control-with-optgroups-for-asp-net-webforms)