# split options in categories in dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

i want to add multiple options in dropdown list with its category.
Like list of designations on basis of its departments but department name should not be selectable. how to do this in asp.net?
eg.

```
--IT--
Programmer
Tester
Analyst
--HR--
Manager
Executive-HR
Sr.Executive–HR Talent Acquisition
```

i forgot to mention, I am binding this from sqlserver database. and binding data in the dropdownlist.

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/130046/1429080)

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing to do with `asp.net` since it can be done with `HTML`

```
<select>
    <optgroup label="--IT--"></optgroup>
    <option value="0">Programmer</option>
    <option value="1">Tester</option>
    <option value="2">Analyst</option>
    <optgroup label="--HR--"></optgroup>
    <option value="3">Manager</option>
    <option value="4">Executive-HR</option>
    <option value="5">Sr.Executive–HR Talent Acquisition</option>
</select>
```

Comment: i got my mistake, dat i provide incomplete data. i forgot to mention, I am binding this from sqlserver database. and binding data in the dropdownlist.

Answer (score 0):

Use the HTML optgroup tag :

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="--IT--">
    <option value="Programmer">Programmer</option>
    <option value="Tester">Tester</option>
    <option value="Analyst">Analyst</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="--HR--">
    <option value="Manager">Manager</option>
    <option value="Executive-HR">Executive-HR</option>
    <option value="Executive-HR-T">Sr.Executive–HR Talent Acquisition</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/E7vj6/)

Comment: i got my mistake dat i provide incomplete data. i forgot to mention, I am binding this from sqlserver database. and binding data in the dropdownlist.

Comment: We have no idea how you receive the data, or how your serverside is set up, so I think you'll have to figure out how to get the data from your database into HTML yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please refer this [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/638625/DropDown-List-With-OptGroup-Support)

Just copy paste two folders and try to add dropdownlist in your project with this below type code

```
 ListItem item1 = new ListItem("Camel", "1");
        item1.Attributes["OptionGroup"] = "Mammals";

        ListItem item2 = new ListItem("Lion", "2");
        item2.Attributes["OptionGroup"] = "Mammals";

        ListItem item3 = new ListItem("Whale", "3");
        item3.Attributes["OptionGroup"] = "Mammals";

        ListItem item4 = new ListItem("Walrus", "4");
        item4.Attributes["OptionGroup"] = "Mammals";

        ListItem item5 = new ListItem("Velociraptor", "5");
        item5.Attributes["OptionGroup"] = "Dinosaurs";

        ListItem item6 = new ListItem("Allosaurus", "6");
        item6.Attributes["OptionGroup"] = "Dinosaurs";

        ListItem item7 = new ListItem("Triceratops", "7");
        item7.Attributes["OptionGroup"] = "Dinosaurs";

        ListItem item8 = new ListItem("Stegosaurus", "8");
        item8.Attributes["OptionGroup"] = "Dinosaurs";

        ListItem item9 = new ListItem("Tyrannosaurus", "9");
        item9.Attributes["OptionGroup"] = "Dinosaurs";


        DDLTest.Items.Add(item1);
        DDLTest.Items.Add(item2);
        DDLTest.Items.Add(item3);
        DDLTest.Items.Add(item4);
        DDLTest.Items.Add(item5);
        DDLTest.Items.Add(item6);
        DDLTest.Items.Add(item7);
        DDLTest.Items.Add(item8);
        DDLTest.Items.Add(item9);
```