# ControlAdapter.LoadAdapterViewState fired before Control.LoadViewState?

Tags: asp.net, adapter, viewstate, web-controls, html-select

I'm writing a `DropDownList` adapter in order to add 2 pieces of functionality to the built in `DropDownLists`, using a combination of the following solutions:

1. [OptionGroup Support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/130046/295813)
2. [Persistence of custom attributes across postback](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3099755/295813)

This works fine if the `DropDownList` items are declared in markup. However, when items are added dynamically I'm relying on the items being restored from `ViewState`.

The problem is that `ControlAdapter.LoadAdapterViewState` gets called **BEFORE** `Control.LoadViewState`, therefore I cannot reapply my OptionGroup/Custom attributes to the `Items` as they don't exist yet.

So firstly, **what is the reasoning behind this order of events?**

And secondly, **where else in the life cycle can I safely set these custom attributes back onto the items?** *Note: PreRender can't be used as the ViewState gets lost if the control is not going to be rendered on the page (e.g. in a wizard).*