# Dropdown item css not working on chrome

Tags: c#, html, css, google-chrome

I have a dropdownlist to which I bind data in c#. After binding, I assigned class to individual items based upon a condition.

```
foreach (ListItem li in ddlTrend.Items)
{
   if (li.Value == "S")
   {
        li.Attributes["class"] = "optionGroup";
   }
   else
   {
        li.Attributes["class"] = "optionChild";
   }
}
```

The code of CSS is

```
.optionGroup {
     font-weight: bold !important;
}

.optionChild {
     padding-left: 15px !important;
}
```

Now this works perfectly in `IE (v 11)` and `Firefox (v 30)`

[image]

but does not works in `Chrome (v 36)`

[image]

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I don't think you can style drop down lists http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript

Comment: Thanks a lot Pete for that link, will see if I can do any workarounds for it

Comment: You could also try using [option groups](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16167862/how-can-i-add-option-groups-in-asp-net-drop-down-list)