# HtmlSelect adding Otpgroup with c# dynamicly

Tags: c#, html

I want to add optgroup to the "HtmlSelect" dynamicly with c#. I am using following code for adding items but i can't find documentation for adding optgroup with c#.
Thanks in advance.

```
   Select1.Items.Add(new ListItem("SomeData", "1"));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add option groups in ASP.NET drop down list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16167862/how-can-i-add-option-groups-in-asp-net-drop-down-list)