# How do we generate OptGroups for Boostrap Multiselect from code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-multiselect

I have used [this bootstrap multiselect](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect) plug-in from GitHub.

I have [read their documentation](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/) on `OptGroup`.  I'm able to get to see these groups by placing group selection from ASPX page.

How do I generate OptGroups from code behind while adding list items?  Is there an attribute that I need to add or is it not possible at all from code behind?

I have dynamic list options so I have to use code behind data source to bind my data source.

**ASPX**

```
<asp:ListBox ID="lstFruits" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" />
```

**Plug-in Initialization**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('[id*=lstFruits]').multiselect({
                includeSelectAllOption: true,
                enableFiltering: true,
                buttonWidth: '50%',
                maxHeight: 200,
                nonSelectedText: 'Select user(s) to send notices...',
                enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
                enableClickableOptGroups: true,
                enableCollapsibleOptGroups: true,

            });
        });
</script>
```

**Sample code behind:**

```
//Group 1
ListItem item1 = new ListItem("Option 1", "1");
ListItem item2 = new ListItem("Option 2", "2");
ListItem item3 = new ListItem("Option 3", "3");
ListItem item4 = new ListItem("Option 4", "4");

//Group 2

ListItem item5 = new ListItem("Option 5", "5");
ListItem item6 = new ListItem("Option 6", "6");
ListItem item7 = new ListItem("Option 7", "7");
ListItem item8 = new ListItem("Option 8", "8");
ListItem item9 = new ListItem("Option 9", "9");

lstFruits.Items.Add(item1);
lstFruits.Items.Add(item2);
lstFruits.Items.Add(item3);
lstFruits.Items.Add(item4);
lstFruits.Items.Add(item5);
lstFruits.Items.Add(item6);
lstFruits.Items.Add(item7);
lstFruits.Items.Add(item8);
lstFruits.Items.Add(item9);
```

I have already looked into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16167862/how-can-i-add-option-groups-in-asp-net-drop-down-list) on SO. It is not related to this plug-in. Though, I still added this code on my code behind.  It still doesn't work.

```
item1.Attributes["OptionGroup"] = "Group 1";
```

Comment: @MichaelCoxon - I have already looked into your link.  That question has no dependency on the plug-in I used. Please consider retrackting your flag.  Thanks

Comment: You need to read the article attached to the answer of that question. Simply adding `item1.Attributes["OptionGroup"]` is not the solution - only part of it. You also need to override the default behaviour of the ASP ListItem since it does not support option groups. The second answer has an updated version of the articles adaptor that is supposedly better.

Comment: @MichaelCoxon - Thanks.  I have overlooked the link in the first answer and the second answer has got me  on the right track.