# How can I iterate over a databound value of an asp.net repeater? (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, repeater, databound

I'd like to iterate over the value of each entry in a c# dictionary within my asp.net repeater.
My `IDictionary` is nothing special - Just key-value pairs of data, and the values are arrays of strings. I'm trying to create a form select element with materializecss ([Docs](https://materializecss.com/select.html), see "Optgroups"). Currently, what I have is this:

```
...
<div class="input-field">
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="optgroupSelect">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <select>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <optgroup label="<%# Eval("Key") %>">
                <%-- Here comes the problem --%>
                <%# foreach (string s in Eval("Value")) { %>
                    <option value="<%=s.toLower()%>"><%=s%></option>
                <%# } %>
            </optgroup>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </select>
            <label>Please select something</label>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>
...
```

I've worked with PHP for the last couple years and feel that I'm missing the mindset of an asp.net dev - Still, I have to do this for work. Obviously, the above code does not work, but it highlights what I'd like to achieve. I've gone through the whole [System.Web.UI.WebControls](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols?view=netframework-4.8) list to maybe find a component which could iterate over the databound value array, but most of them have their own style which I don't want (since everything should match with materializecss).
I appreciate any help towards solving this, thanks for taking your time!

**Note:** My pages are `.aspx` Web Forms in the Asp.net Framework 4.8

Comment: Any ideas in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130020/dropdownlist-control-with-optgroups-for-asp-net-webforms/27784921#27784921)?

Comment: @wazz Thanks a lot, that was what I was looking for ^^ What a bummer I wasn't able to find that answer during my search :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dropdownlist control with <optgroup>s for asp.net (webforms)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130020/dropdownlist-control-with-optgroups-for-asp-net-webforms/27784921#27784921)